# How to revoke access token from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox-api

Is there any way how to revoke an access token using Dropbox API (either HTTP or JAVA lib)? The same functionality as `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke` for Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#disable-token. (You need to use API v1. I don't believe there's yet an equivalent in API v2.)

Comment: Works fine, thanx. For Java it is DbxClientV1.disableAccessToken() method

Answer (score 1):

There are different endpoints for different versions of the Dropbox API:

### V2

- HTTP reference:
  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-revoke

### V1:

- HTTP reference: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#disable-token
- Java reference: http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.8.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#disableAccessToken()